# Programmatically add Proxy Repositories and edit a Repository group in Nexus (Helm Chart)

Tags: nexus

I am automatically building our dev environment (prow, tekton, kaniko, nexus, vault, etc) on a Kubernetes cluster. So that I am able to quickly rebuild the dev environment on a different Kuberentes cluster if needed. I am using [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) for that which is realy nice!

The nexus repository server I am using is build from a [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/sonatype-nexus). For my applications to be able to build out of the box, by just communicating to our Nexus server, I need to add two other Nexus (mvn) repositories, which are not in maven-central, and add those to the maven-group.

This is pretty easy to do in the Nexus UI. I would however like to do this automatically when the helm chart is provisioning. I've read some stuff [here](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-apt/issues/66) about using the [Script API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api). I could possibly dive into that and get that working, but it seems like a complex solution to a simple problem. Are there any alternative methods possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to do this with a script then I originally anticipated, haven't tested it, but I guess the `create-repos.json` could look something like this:

```
{
    "name": "create-repos",
    "type": "groovy",
    "content": "repository.createMavenProxy('proxy-foo','https://foo.example.com/maven-group'); repository.createMavenProxy('proxy-bar', 'https://bar.example.com/maven-group'); repository.createMavenGroup('foobar-group', ['maven-public', 'proxy-foo', 'proxy-bar'], 'default');"
}
```

After this is created, upload, run and delete the script using some shell commands:

```
curl -v -X POST -u admin:admin123 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    'http://nexus.jx.cluster/service/rest/v1/script' -d @create-repos.json
curl -v -X POST -u admin:admin123 --header "Content-Type: text/plain" \
    'http://nexus.jx.cluster/service/rest/v1/script/create-repos/run'
curl -v -X DELETE -u admin:admin123 \
    'http://nexus.jx.cluster/service/rest/v1/script/create-repos'
```

Tested and worked for me!